# Laravel 5.4 Credit, Debit and Balance Calculation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

Now I am doing Invoice Application using Laravel Framework 5.4.

I Save Credit and Debit Amount in Transaction Table. I want to Display Credit amount, Debit amount, Balance Amount in Blade Template (same as like below)

[image]

Comment: Transaction::Select('*','(credit - debit) as Balance')->get(); @EddyTheDove

Comment: Please add a code snippet to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Controller :

$transaction = DB::table('transaction')->get();

In your Blade :

```
        <?php $tbalance=0; ?>
       @foreach($transaction as $trans)
         <tr>
<td>{{$invaccstatements->ref_no}} </td>
<td>{{number_format($invaccstatements->credit, 2)}}</td>
<td>{{number_format($invaccstatements->debit, 2)}}</td>
<td align="right"><?php $chkbala = $invaccstatements->credit - $invaccstatements->debit;  echo $tbalance += $chkbala; ?></td>
</tr> 
    @endforeach
```

Comment: <?php $tbalance=0; ?>
       @foreach($transaction as $trans)
         <tr>
<td>{{$trans->ref_no}} </td>
<td>{{number_format($trans->credit, 2)}}</td>
<td>{{number_format($trans->debit, 2)}}</td>
<td align="right"><?php $chkbala = $trans->credit - $trans->debit;  echo $tbalance += $chkbala; ?></td>
</tr> 
    @endforeach