# Use Credit and Debit amount to calculate Balance in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.4

I have a Transaction table which contains the following data:

[image]

I Need Laravel Query which gives Following Result.

[image]

Comment: You 2 have the same pb. Check my answer there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42687388/laravel-5-4-credit-debit-and-balance-calculation/42687874#42687874. Is it like a school assignment?

Comment: Hey you Code is Wrong.. Do you understand my pbm... @EddyTheDove

Comment: yes, I do. You increment the values. you can do that in a loop. Is it the reason you downvoted my answer because I didn't do the foreach loop for you?